# Eclipse Luna CDT: What is a header variant?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, codan

I am having difficulty getting the Eclipse Indexer (Codan) to recognize certain data declarations in header files. There is a new preference to [Index all header variants](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn83#Preferences_for_header_variants), but little explanation as to what this means. Enabling the preference seems to fix the problem. But I still would like to know what the preference does exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have header `a.h` like this:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef SYMBOL
#define SYMBOL int
#endif

struct S
{
  SYMBOL sym;
};
```

And now if you include your header like this:

```
struct UserSymbol
{
  int i, j, k;
};

#define SYMBOL UserSymbol

#include "a.h"

S var;

int main()
{
  var.sym.i = 123;
  return 0;
}
```

then Eclipse CDT may not to recognize `sym.i`.

You may have more complex examples with deeper nested inclusions or so on.

EDIT:

But if you include the `a.h` to the "Index all variants of specific headers" list or check "Index all header variants" Eclipse will build several variants of the `a.h` indexes and will "know" that you have defined the your specific `SYMBOL`.

Comment: What's `s` in this case?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod, Eclipse will think about `sym.i` like about erroneous construction, will emphasize it with wavy red line, will mark it with warning sign and (IMHO this is most important) will not show a hint when you place mouse pointer over the `i` symbol.

Comment: But `s` is not defined either.

Comment: Why won't Eclipse CDT recognize `sym.i`? The header is included once in the module, and `SYMBOL` is defined before the inclusion. Am I missing something?

Comment: Same as @ysap, I do not understand why "Eclipse CDT *may* not to recognize `sym.i`" (and why "may", in which cases "may" is "will"?).
In addition to an example I do not understand (although others do, and in particular the OP is satisfied with the answer), I do not see how "What is a header variant?", from the title, is answered.

Comment: In the example, SYMBOL has two possible definitions (i.e. variants). Eclipse *may* not recognize `sym.i` depending on which variant was indexed. If "index all header variants" is checked, it should recognize both possibilities.